# How to calculate percentages of items in a list that meet specific criteria?

Tags: python, css, object, methods

I am making a program that looks at a file with data for hail in the U.S. I have successfully created a class with objects (All the states), and have the state abbreviation, number of total hail reports, and list of hail sizes for each state/object.

I have to make a table showing statistics of the hail sizes for each state. I created a method that averages the hail sizes for each state, but I can't figure out how to make a method that calculates the percentages of hail sizes that fall within a certain size range.

The table has 5 categories, for these hail sizes: <1.25, 1.25-1.99, 2.0-2.49, 2.5-2.99, >3.0.
I am pretty sure I need to do a rolling sum for each category, but I just can't figure out how to do it with so  many categories. If I could do a rolling sum, it would just be that sum/ the total number of reports for that state.

Here is the code I have so far:

```css
class stateHail:
    def __init__(self, state):
        self.stateAbbr = state
        self.hailReports = 0
        self.hailSize = []

    def avgSize(self):
        self.avg = (sum(self.hailSize))/self.hailReports
    
    #def percents(self):
        #???
        
#Creates objects needed for class

states = []
for x in ["AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", "MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY", "PR", "VA", "VI"]:
    stateObject = stateHail(x)
    states.append(stateObject)

#Opens file and assigns state abbreviation, hail report number, and list of hail sizes to each object/state

fileHail = open("90-99_hail.csv", "r")
try:
    for line in fileHail:
        splitLine=line.split(",")
        abbrFile=splitLine[7]
        for x in states:
            if (abbrFile==x.stateAbbr):
                x.hailSize.append(float(splitLine[10]))
                x.hailReports = x.hailReports + 1
        
except:
    fileHail.close()

#Calculates average for each state

for x in states:
    if (x.hailReports>100):
        x.avgSize()
        print x.avg
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can store the percentages of each range in a list. The code may look something as follows

```
    self.percentages = [(self.hailSize[i]/self.hailReports) * 100 for i in range(5)]
```

Comment: This gets the first five hail sizes, divides them by the total number of hail reports, and multiplies those figures by 100. For hail sizes of `[1,2,2,3,1,4,2,3,1]`, that would result in a list of `[20, 40, 40, 60, 20]`, which doesn't correspond to anything meaningful.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3,  danielle may be able to clarify, but I have assumed self.hailSize[i] to contain the total number of reported hailstorms of particular size. i.e self.hailSize[0] may contain total hailReports with size '<1.25'.

Comment: I think `self.hailSize` contains a list of each recorded hail. If it hailed three times, with the first being 0.7 in size, the next 1.2 in size, and the last 1.1 in size, `self.hailSize` would be `[0.7,1.2,1.1]`. `self.avgSize()` relies on that setup, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of hail sizes like this: `[1.1,1.1,1.6,1.6,2.1,2.6,3.1,3.1,3.1]`

you can get a list like this: `[2, 2, 1, 1, 3]`

from this:

```
return [len([item for item in self.hailSize if small<=item<big]) for small,big in [(0,1.25), (1.25,2), (2,2.5), (2.5,3), (3,200)]]
```

By the way, instead of saving a `self.hailReports` variable to count how many elements there are in `self.hailSize`, you can just use `len(self.hailSize)`. Next, have `avgSize()` simply do `return sum(self.hailSize)/len(self.hailSize)`, and then you don't have to call a function to update a variable all the time - just get the average size with `avgSize()`.